# ReactJS/Flask app to render a given JSX file that is added after "npm build"

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

I'm trying to build a react app that can render a JSX file that is added/modified after npm build.

More details below

I have a single page react app with various data table and chart components, which fetch data from flask backend. All those components are put together in a single JSX file (result.jsx).

After "npm build" I might need to change the data contents or layout of the page, (e.g adding additional tables/charts to the page). By modifying the flask backend, data contents can be updated easily but as for the layout I currently need to modify the result.jsx and npm build again.

Is there a way to avoid doing npm build whenever result.jsx file is changed?
I'd like to keep result.jsx outside of the npm build to keep it flexible, and have the react frontend to simply mirror this resuit.jsx

Answer (score 0):

In your build output, you don't have a running process that picks up JS files in a directory, it's all concatenated together into one file. JSX is compiled to JS through the build tools and isn't understood by the browser without that step anyway.

If you want components that respond to data, you'll have to code them to do that. You may be able to do something with React Router and dynamic routing, but that'll still point to coded component files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Yatrix. Yes I do understand all JSX/JS files are bundled into one or more chunks after build. I'm happy for those table and chart components to be in that bundle, but am trying to see if having the result.jsx file separate to that bundle is possible at all. 
The benefit is that I don't need to re-build when I make changes to that file. By keeping this result.jsx file flexible, I can add more data or charts to it when I need to. Is this possible?

Comment: result.jsx is simply going to be <div><someTableComponent source="/foo" />...</div>